# matlab: find interpolation function in 3d

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I got datapoints for a function f: R^3->R, i.e. I got `x1, x2, x3` and for each combination of different values of `x1, x2, x3` I got a value for `f`. For example

```
x1 = 1:10, x2 = 1:6, x3 = 1:8
```

then I got 10*6*8=480 values for `f`.

I know there is a function `interp3` which does interpolation in 3d space, but only for a given set of query points.

Now my question: I would like to have some kind of general expression for the function `f`, i.e. something like `f(x1,x2,x3) = ...` where the dots represent a function fitting the above data best and is a "closed form" expression. For example if it fits best linear in `x1`, quadratic in `x2` and constant in `x3` then `f` would be something like `f(x1,x2,x3) = a*x1 + b*x2^2 +c` and `a, b, c` are fix numbers. So basically there are two things i would like to solve:

1. How is `f` depending on the data, i.e. the general expression (as above with `a*x1 + b*x2^2 +c`)
2. get the best value for `a,b,c` to fit the given data.

Is there a way matlab can solve this/these two problem/s, such that it calculates a good function expression for `f` depending on `x1, x2, x3`? And if not (because I guess 1. is quite difficult to solve?!) is there a possibility to 'assume' `f` has a given form (like `f(x1,x2,x3) = a*x1^2 + b*x2^2 +c*x3^2` or something else) and then find the best values that fit this form with the given data?

Also now you see that I can not use interp3 (at least I guess so) because I don't have this 'closed form' expression.

Comment: Great Thank. I had a look at it, but apparently it's only for 1 or 2 dimensions: "Data to fit, specified as a matrix with either one (curve fitting) or two (surface fitting) columns". Furthermore, in the "See Also" tab nothing for 3d is mentioned?! It also looks like 'polyfit' is only for 1d, isn't it?

Comment: But this looks promising: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/116762 at least for 2. in my question. 1. I probably have to handle myeself?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want an mathematical expression which is nearly describing your 3D data. Probably the best solution for you is MATLAB's surface fitting tool. Open surface tool using `sftool` instruction. Then insert your data, `X, Y, Z`. Afterwards choose `Custom Equation` from the list in center of the window and then insert your desirable fit function and then simply click the fit button. If nothing goes wrong, the coefficients (your `a,b,c`) of the custom function would appear in the left side of the window in `Results` section.

Comment: The thing is that I got data `X1, X2, X3, F`, i.e. one dimension more. So I want a mathematical expression, which is nearly describing 4D data: 3D input and 1D output.